# How to resolve " invalid operands of types 'const char [ ]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+' "

Tags: c++, qt, c-str

I use Qt Creator and this code :

```
string execpath = "";
execpath += (QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).toStdString();
WinExec("ffmpeg -f dshow -t 32 -i audio=\"virtual-audio-capturer\" -y "+(execpath.c_str())+"\\sound.mp3", SW_HIDE); // Loopback captured in sound.mp3
```

generate this issue on line 3 :

> invalid operands of types 'const char [60]' and 'const char*' to
>   binary 'operator+'

How to solve it?

Comment: You can't add together C-style strings with the + operator

Comment: Concatenate the strings first, and *then* call `.c_str()` on the concatenated `std::string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want something like:

```
execpath += (QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).toStdString();
std::string cmd = "ffmpeg -f dshow -t 32 -i audio=\"virtual-audio-capturer\" -y "
WinExec((cmd +execpath +"\\sound.mp3").c_str(), SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: execpath is a variable that I use a lot in my code but I guess you are right

Comment: This works :

    WinExec(string("ffmpeg -f dshow -t 32 -i audio=\"virtual-audio-capturer\" -y "+execpath+"\\sound.mp3").c_str(), SW_HIDE); // Loopback captured in sound.mp3